# Is it possible to calculate the eigenvalue for the spin vector $\hat S_x |↑_z⟩ $?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

Or must the spin state being measured be in the same direction as $\hat S_x $?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense. $\hat{S}_x|\uparrow_z\rangle$ is not an operator, it's a vector, so you can't compute its eigenvalue, because it doesn't  have one, because it's not an operator. You *can* compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\hat{S}_x$, though. They are $\pm\hbar/2$ and $|\uparrow_z\rangle \pm |\downarrow_z\rangle$. Can you clarify your question?  Also, "must the spin state being measured be in the same direction as the operator"  doesn't make sense either...

Comment: ...because the quantity measured *corresponds* to an operator, so we choose the operator based on what measurement we're making. Can you clarify?

Comment: My apologies, I've corrected the terminology now.

Comment: The question is still incoherent. What do you mean by “the vector $S_x$?” $S_x$ is not a vector.

Comment: Hopefully, I've made it more clear now.

Comment: $\hat{S}_x$ is an operator, $|\uparrow_z\rangle$ is a state(-vector) and so is $\hat{S}_x|\uparrow_z\rangle$. It only makes sense to talk about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an operator, i.e. $\hat{S}_x$. Also: $\hat{S}_x$ does not indicate a direction, since it is an operator, and not a vector in the 3-dimensional coordinate space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to calculate the eigenvalue for the spin vector $ S_x |↑_z⟩ $?

If you are asking whether $S_x|\uparrow_z\rangle$ *is* an eigenvector of some operator, the answer is yes.
$$
S_x|\uparrow_z\rangle = \frac{1}{2}|\downarrow_z\rangle\;,
$$
which is an eigenvector of $S_z$ with eigenvalue $-1$.

---

If you are asking whether or not it is possible to find the eigenvectors of $S_x$, the answer is yes.

In terms of eigenvectors of $S_z$ you can write the eigenvectors of $S_x$ as:
$$
|+\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow_z\rangle + |\downarrow_z\rangle\right)
$$
and
$$
|-\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow_z\rangle - |\downarrow_z\rangle\right)
$$

Comment: I think it should be $S_x|\uparrow\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(S_++S_-)|\uparrow\rangle=|\downarrow\rangle/2$.

Comment: Yes. You are right. $S_x = \sigma_x/2$. I will update.